# XGBoost, handling continous and fixed data for loan dataset

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, xgboost

**Background:**

I am using XGBoost to develop a model to predict whether a particular loan will default or not. I have now included time-series data on Fico score, and other variables that change throughout time. Thus I have 13,202 unique loans but with over 300,000 rows with variable and fixed data.

**Question:**

Given that I have data that is changing through time and some data that will remain fixed throughout time like lot size and square footage of the property can XGBoost differentiate between a mix of fixed data and variable data? Also, when splitting my data into a training and testing set, is their a way of doing so such that the loans itself are split up accordingly and not just the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of building machine learning models for prediction and there are pros and cons for each method.

However, my principle is that **no matter what I do and how I generate new features, I will NOT change the granularity of the data**. For example, in this case, if I'm predicting if a loan will default or not, then my row will be unique loans, no single loan will appear more than once in my training/testing data.

This leads to how you should be generating new features. You mentioned that you have time series related data (i.e. feature values at different time points for each loan). What I will probably do at this point is to expand the data horizontally instead of vertically.

I will do something like:

```
    loan_id feat1_t1   feat1_t2   feat1_t3   feat2 ...
          1        5          7          8     0.2 ...
```

This way I'm still keeping only 1 row for each loan_id. `feat1` is the variable that's collected at different time points, thus `_t1`, `_t2` and `_t3`. And for variables that are fixed, I will only have 1 column (i.e. `feat2`).

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. I assume that if I did not do the following there would be an issue with how the model would know whether each row would be the same loan or if it would be a new loan?

Comment: @Wolfy That's correct. It's possible to do it in your way but it requires extra attention to the details. I would say even if it works, I would personally prefer the way I used to do this type of work.

Comment: Thanks ill give that a try.

Comment: In my understanding, XGboost, like a lot of other tree-ensemble methods, randomly samples features during the tree building process. If the features are constructed this way, how is the ordinal aspect of time taken into account? It seems to me that, using XGBoost, or another tree ensemble method, the very important inter-subject correlation via time, could be lost, or not be taken into account. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Wolfy Your concern is correct in my opinion, and it's difficult for XGBoost to take care of everything. It also depends on the nature of your modeling data. If ther eare a lot of time series variables, and they are important, I might depart from XGBoost and try other models like LSTM RNN.